How can I mouse click on two different applications at the same time?
I have two applications open. I need to mouse click on a button on each application at the same time. This is for video editing. Is there an ubuntu or linux feature which can help with this ?
The screen position (x & y coordinates) of both buttons on each app are known beforehand. I just need a click to be pressed simultaneously.

In principle, you cannot click on two different positions at the same time, just like you also cannot input two letters at the same time. In any case, each event will be processed separately if registered by the system, and, when registered, if not discarded from the input buffer.
For practical purposes, you can automate such that pressing a single shortcut key automatically triggers the two clicks. This can be achieved with input simulation tools like dotool or ydotool. These tools allow to programmatically simulate mouse and keyboard input.
Thus, a command that 1) clicks on the first button and immediately after 2) clicks on the other button can be assigned to a custom shortcut key, or can be included in an executable script, which in turn can be assigned to a custom shortcut key. Hitting the shortcut key will then trigger the two clicks.
